# Scala: Update Array inside a Map

Tags: scala

I am creating a Map which has an Array inside it. I need to keep adding values to that Array. How do I do that?

```
var values: Map[String, Array[Float]] = Map()
```

I tried several ways such as:

```
myobject.values.getOrElse("key1", Array()).++(Array(float1))
```

Few other ways to but nothing updates the array inside the Map.

Comment: How you would like to update the array? Change the value at the position or append / prepend it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a problem with this code:

```
values.getOrElse("key1", Array()).++(Array(float1))
```

This does not update the `Map` in `values`, it just creates a new `Array` and then throws it away.

You need to replace the original `Map` with a new, updated `Map`, like this:

```
values = values.updated("key1", values.getOrElse("key1", Array.empty[Float]) :+ float1)
```

---

To understand this you need to be clear on the distinction between mutable variables and mutable data.

`var` is used to create a *mutable variable* which means that the variable can be assigned a new value, e.g.

```
var name = "John"
name = "Peter" // Would not work if name was a val
```

By contrast *mutable data* is held in objects whose contents can be changed

```
val a = Array(1,2,3)
a(0) = 12 // Works even though a is a val not a var
```

In your example `values` is a mutable variable but the `Map` is immutable so it can't be changed. You have to create a new, immutable, `Map` and assign it to the mutable `var`.

Comment: Replace the whole map with the original map? Wouldn't that be VERY costly! I mean at any given point there could be over 50 keys in the Map & each key might have more than 200 values. I thought I was using 'var' not 'val' so I am using 'mutable' objects no?

Comment: Immutable data-structures reuse whatever possible and are relatively cheap.

Comment: There is some cost but it is not as bad as you think because the data structures are optimised for this sort of operation. But if you need the best performance you need to use `scala.collection.mutable.Map` which does allow elements to be updated. (As I explained values in a `var` are not necessarily mutable)

Comment: Here is nice visualisation of some scala collections: https://stanch.github.io/reftree/talks/Immutability.html I envy you. Discovering this is real joy :)

Comment: I am working on a streaming app which will process millions of rows per minute so this Map will get rebuilt constantly. This solution is a bit scary but seems like you guys are experts so I will give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Getting Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found. Will try Ivan's solution. Is there a downside to his solution?

Comment: @DilTeam I've changed to code to avoid the exception (I was trying to keep it simple)

Comment: Please don't trust Us because we are experts. This topic deserves to be understood, not copied. Only you can tell what is needed in your exact case.

Answer (score 4):

From what I can see (according to `++`), you would like to append `Array`, with one more element. But `Array` fixed length structure, so instead I'd recommend to use `Vector`. Because, I suppose, you are using immutable `Map` you need update it as well.

So the final solution might look like:

```
var values: Map[String, Vector[Float]] = Map()
val key = "key1"
val value = 1.0
values = values + (key -> (values.getOrElse(key, Vector.empty[Float]) :+ value))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for suggested issue, I changed it to `Vector`

Comment: This looks promising... but I just want to understand...This will NOT 'rebuild' the entire 'values' vector, correct? I simply want to add an element to the Vector. Since the 'values' is 'mutable' object I am assuming this code will not rebuild it. Please confirm. Thanks.

Comment: Is there no way to simply get the 'reference' of the Vector & add element to the vector using that reference? This is how I would do it in Java. Sorry.. bit new to Scala. Thanks.

Comment: @DilTeam no, because both `Map` and internal `Vector` structures are both immutable any modification will create new instance with copied values, it won't work like regular mutable Java's `Map` and `ArrayList` which mutates the internal state. But, immutable structures are highly recommended practice in Scala world on the other hand.

Comment: @DilTeam , Tim's answer explains it best. While you may *assume* the map you are getting is a whole new map, under the hood, Scala may use mutable data structures and other tricks to make the operation as efficient as it can be. You don't need to worry about that.

Comment: @DilTeam `Is there no way to simply get the 'reference'` - as I mentioned, because of using immutable structures you won't be able to just get and modify internal `Vector` reference, because `:+` will create new one, which need to be changed in outer map

Comment: Note that this doesn't compile, that `Nil` is not compatible with `Vector[Float]` and `value` needs to be `Float` not `Double`

Comment: @DilTeam If you want to be able to update in place, the type of `values` needs to be `mutable.Map[String, mutable.ArrayBuffer[Float]]` (and `import scala.collection.mutable`). Then there are methods to `update` the `Map` and `append` to the `Array`.

Comment: @DilTeam see my answer. There is mutable/mutable solution (m4).

Answer (score 4):

## Immutable vs Mutable Collections

**You need to choose** what type of collection you will use **`immutable` or `mutable`** one. Both are great and works totally **differently**. I guess you are familiar with `mutable` one (from other languages), but `immutable` are default in scala and probably you are using it in your code (because it doesn't need any imports). Immutable `Map` cannot be changed... you can only create new one with updated values (Tim's and Ivan's answers covers that).

There are **few ways** to solve your problem and all are good **depending on use case**.

See implementation below (m1 to m6):

```scala
//just for convenience 
type T = String
type E = Long

import scala.collection._

//immutable map with immutable seq (default).
var m1 = immutable.Map.empty[T,List[E]] 

//mutable map with immutable seq. This is great for most use-cases.
val m2 = mutable.Map.empty[T,List[E]]

//mutable concurrent map with immutable seq.
//should be fast and threadsafe (if you know how to deal with it) 
val m3 = collection.concurrent.TrieMap.empty[T,List[E]] 

//mutable map with mutable seq.
//should be fast but could be unsafe. This is default in most imperative languages (PHP/JS/JAVA and more).
//Probably this is what You have tried to do
val m4 = mutable.Map.empty[T,mutable.ArrayBuffer[E]] 

//immutable map with mutable seq.
//still could be unsafe 
val m5 = immutable.Map.empty[T,mutable.ArrayBuffer[E]] 
//immutable map with mutable seq v2 (used in next snipped)
var m6 = immutable.Map.empty[T,mutable.ArrayBuffer[E]]

//Oh... and NEVER DO THAT, this is wrong
//I mean... don't keep mutable Map in `var`
//var mX = mutable.Map.empty[T,...]
```

Other answers show `immutable.Map` with `immutable.Seq` and this is preferred way (or default at least). It costs something but for most apps it is perfectly ok. Here You have nice source of info about immutable data structures: https://stanch.github.io/reftree/talks/Immutability.html.

Each variant has it's own Pros and Cons. Each deals with updates differently, and it makes this question **much harder than it looks** at the first glance.

## Solutions

```scala
val k = "The Ultimate Answer"
val v = 42f

//immutable map with immutable seq (default).
m1 = m1.updated(k, v :: m1.getOrElse(k, Nil))

//mutable map with immutable seq.
m2.update(k, v :: m2.getOrElse(k, Nil))

//mutable concurrent map with immutable seq.
//m3 is bit harder to do in scala 2.12... sorry :)

//mutable map with mutable seq.
m4.getOrElseUpdate(k, mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Float]) += v

//immutable map with mutable seq.
m5 = m5.updated(k, {
  val col = m5.getOrElse(k, c.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[E])
  col += v
  col
})

//or another implementation of immutable map with mutable seq.
m6.get(k) match {
  case None => m6 = m6.updated(k, c.mutable.ArrayBuffer(v))
  case Some(col) => col += v
}
```

**check scalafiddle** with this implementations. https://scalafiddle.io/sf/WFBB24j/3. 
This is great tool (ps: you can always save `CTRL+S` your changes and share link to write question about your snippet).

Oh... and if You care about concurrency (`m3` case) then write another question. Such topic deserve to be in separate thread :)

## (im)mutable api VS (im)mutable Collections

You can have **mutable collection** and still use immutable api that **will copy orginal seq**. For example `Array` is mutable:

```scala
val example = Array(1,2,3) 
example(0) = 33 //edit in place
println(example.mkString(", ")) //33, 2, 3
```

But some functions on it (e.g. `++`) will create new sequence... not change existing one:

```scala
val example2 = example ++ Array(42, 41) //++ is immutable operator
println(example.mkString(", ")) //33, 2, 3  //example stays unchanged
println(example2.mkString(", ")) //33, 2, 3, 42, 41 //but new sequence is created
```

There is method `updateWith` that is mutable and will exist **only in mutable** sequences. There is also `updatedWith` and it **exists in both immutable AND mutable** collections and if you are not careful enough you will use wrong one (yea ... 1 letter more).

This means you need to be careful which functions you are using, immutable or mutable one. Most of the time you can distinct them by result type. If something returns collection then it will be probably some kind of copy of original seq. It result is unit then it is mutable for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have immutable Map with mutable array (as given in my original question.) Your four examples don't cover that, right? Both Tim's & Ivan's solutions worked for me. I am sticking to Tim's because that allows me to continue using Array.

Comment: Neither Tim's or Ivan answers is `immutable.Map[mutable.Seq]` to be honest. Both are `immutable.Map[immutable.Seq]` in core because they use only immutable api.

Comment: @DilTeam see my updated answer. If it is helpful upvote please (I put too much work into it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Scala 2.13's [transform](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#transform[W](f:(K,V)=%3EW):CC[K,W]) function to transform your map anyway you want.

```
val values = Map("key" -> Array(1f, 2f, 3f), "key2" -> Array(4f,5f,6f))

values.transform {
  case ("key", v) => v ++ Array(6f)
  case (_,v) => v
}
```

Result:

```
Map(key -> Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0), key2 -> Array(4.0, 5.0, 6.0))
```

Note that appending to arrays takes linear time so you might want to consider a more efficient data structure such as `Vector` or `Queue` or even a `List` (if you can afford to prepend rather than append).

**Update**:

However, if it is only one key you want to update, it is probably better to use `updatedWith`:

```
values.updatedWith("key")(_.map(_ ++ Array(6f)))
```

which will give the same result. The nice thing about the above code is that if the key does not exist, it will not change the map at all without throwing any error.

Comment: One more thing. In update you use `updateWith` in text and `updatedWith` in snipped ... those are different functions :). I think it could confuse.